# xcode Sprite Kit Score counts and Coin is removed before Hero touches it

Tags: sprite, scoring

I am a Newbie, and I am making my first game. Everything is working great accept when I added coins.

-(void)spawnCoin {

```
SKNode* coinNode = [SKNode node];
coinNode.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + 150 + (arc4random() % 100), 0 );
coinNode.zPosition = -10;

CGFloat y = arc4random() % (NSInteger)( self.frame.size.height / 2 ) + 40;

SKTexture* coinTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Coins_1"];
coinTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* coinTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Coins_2"];
coinTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* coinTexture3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Coins_3"];
coinTexture3.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* coinTexture4 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Coins_4"];
coinTexture4.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* coinTexture5 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Coins_5"];
coinTexture5.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* coinTexture6 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Coins_6"];
coinTexture6.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKAction* spin = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[coinTexture1, coinTexture2, coinTexture3, coinTexture4, coinTexture5, coinTexture6] timePerFrame:0.05]];
_coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:coinTexture6];
[_coin runAction:spin];


[_coin setScale:1.0];
_coin.position = CGPointMake( 0, y );
_coin.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_coin.size];
_coin.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
_coin.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory;
_coin.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = birdCategory;

[coinNode addChild:_coin];
[coinNode runAction:_moveCoinsAndRemove];
[_coins addChild:coinNode];

SKNode* contactNode = [SKNode node];
contactNode.position = CGPointMake(0,y);
contactNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_coin.size];
contactNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
contactNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory;
contactNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = birdCategory;
[_coin addChild:contactNode];
```

}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

  if (_score > _heighscore) {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_score forKey:@"HighScoreSave"];

  ```
  // Vibrate
  AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
  ```

  }

  if( _moving.speed > 0 ) {
      if( ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory ) {

  ```
      // contact with score entity

      SKNode* coinNode = contact.bodyB.node;
      [coinNode removeFromParent];
      coinNode.hidden = YES;

      _score++;


      _scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_score];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this,

coinNode.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 1 + _coin.size.width / 1 - 50 + (arc4random() % 50), 0 );
    coinNode.zPosition = -10;

```
CGFloat y = arc4random() % (NSInteger)( self.frame.size.height / 2 ) + 20;
```

But now I have a NEW problem. When my hero hits the coins they react like obstacles and he is killed instead of just counting and vanishing. It add to to the score for the hit, but also stops the entire game as if the hero has been killed.

Here is my code:

```
[_coin setScale:1.0];
_coin.position = CGPointMake( 0, y );
_coin.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_coin.size];
_coin.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
_coin.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
_coin.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = coinCategory;
_coin.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
_coin.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = birdCategory;

[coinNode addChild:_coin];

SKNode* coinContactNode = [SKNode node];
coinContactNode.position = CGPointMake( _bird.size.width / 0.5, CGRectGetMidY( _coin.frame ) );
coinContactNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(_coin.size.width, _coin.size.height)];
coinContactNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
coinContactNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
coinContactNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = coinCategory;
coinContactNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
coinContactNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = birdCategory;
[_coin addChild:coinContactNode];

 [coinNode runAction:_moveCoinsAndRemove];

    [_coins addChild:coinNode];
```

And here:

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

  if (_score > _heighscore) {

  ```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_score forKey:@"HighScoreSave"];
  // Sound effect – Score
  [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Tap_It_Real_Good.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
  // Vibrate
  AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
  ```

  }

  if( _moving.speed > 0 ) {

  ```
        if( ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & coinCategory ) == coinCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & coinCategory ) == coinCategory ) {


      _score2++;
      _scoreLabelNode2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_score2];

      // Sound effect – Score
      [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Tap_It.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];


      // Add a little visual feedback for the score increment
      [_scoreLabelNode2 runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction scaleTo:1.5 duration:0.2], [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:0.2]]]];
  }


  if( ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory ) {




      // Bird has contact with score entity
      _score++;

      // Sound effect – Score
      [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Tap_It.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];

      _scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_score];

      // Add a little visual feedback for the score increment
      [_scoreLabelNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction scaleTo:1.5 duration:0.2], [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:0.2]]]];




  } else {
      // Bird has collided with world

      _moving.speed = 0;


      _bird.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = worldCategory;

      _coins.speed = 0;

        _bird.speed = 0;


      [_bird runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI * _bird.position.y * 0.01 duration:_bird.position.y * 0.003] completion:^{

      }];

      // Sound effect – Collision
      [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Tap_It.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
      // Vibrate
      AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);


      // Flash background if contact is detected
      [self removeActionForKey:@"flash"];
      [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{
          self.backgroundColor = [SKColor redColor];
      }], [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05], [SKAction runBlock:^{
          self.backgroundColor = _skyColor;
      }], [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05]]] count:4], [SKAction runBlock:^{
          _canRestart = YES;
      }]]] withKey:@"flash"];
  }
  ```

  }
  }

Any help. Thanks :)